# Pdfbookmark for abstract and table of contents (toc)

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, article

I am trying to set a bookmark of my abstract and my table of contents. The bookmark for the abstracts works fine but the bookmark for the toc links to the abstract instead to the toc. If I remove

```
\pdfbookmark[section]{Abstract}{toc}
```

the contents bookmark links fine to the toc...

I do not see where the mistake is and am thankful for any help!

Her is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref, bookmark}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Abstract %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[section]{Abstract}{toc}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Chapters %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cleardoublepage
\section{Introduction}
\cleardoublepage
\section{Sec 2}
\cleardoublepage
\section{Sec 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last argument of `\pdfbookmark` becomes the main part of the intern anchor name for the bookmark. The two invocations of `\pdfbookmark` use both `toc` with the same level. Therefore the document has two destinations with the same name, but a destination name must be unique. Thus instead of `toc`, the first `\pdfbookmark` could use `abstract`. Also `\phantomsection` is not needed, because `\pdfbookmark` already creates an anchor.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref, bookmark}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Abstract %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[section]{Abstract}{abstract}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Chapters %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cleardoublepage
\section{Introduction}
\cleardoublepage
\section{Sec 2}
\cleardoublepage
\section{Sec 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Easy one but sometimes you just don't see it. Thanks for the hint that I do not need the `\phantompage` before  `\pdfbookmark`! :)